# beginner: python script to log and graph my funds

Tags: python, graph

I have an investment plan but their tools are not complete.
I'd like to gather all the values from `boursorama` for example and to log them in a file that I can see afterwards with all the graphs on the same screen. I'm a beginner in `python` and need you help, here is what I started already (took me 2 days...)

```
import modules
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

LU0078041133 = 'http://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/opcvm.phtml?symbole=MP-302233'
LU0237698914 = 'http://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/opcvm.phtml?symbole=MP-217523'
LU0011889929 = ''
LU0432979614 = ''
LU0095938881 = ''
GB0002769312 = ''
LU0069152568 = ''
LU0006277684 = ''


req = urllib.request.Request(LU0237698914)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

cotation = re.findall(r'cotation\">(.*?)USD',str(respData))
print ('Fidelity Funds Global Property A Acc USD:', cotation)
```

Thanks for your help and advise

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Maybe have a look here first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  It seems that you are not asking a single question, but multiples. I'd recommend to complete a python tutorial first and then come back to your original task.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know where to search and if I was searching from the clearest side.

Answer (score 0):

You may:

- Look at Python Pandas, a great library to do math on data and render it graphically
- Look at ipython notebook, a nice way to play with pandas with inline graphs
- Look what already exists like [searching Boursorama on github](https://github.com/search?l=python&q=boursorama&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
- You should probably use `requests` instead of `urllib`, it's more readable
- You should use a dictionary instead of different variables to store your mapping between ISIN codes and links
- You shall not ask a so vague question in so, as said in comment.